# Can I make a ladder system(like battle.net) with using just game center?

Tags: iphone, game-center

I made a game with cocos2d for iOS. and I will put a network kit for people to play multiplay game. but I wanna put also a ranking system so that people would see how well he does.

but I don't wanna make a server.. nor do something, so I just wanna use a game center leader board. Do you think is this OK?

I mean people play with random people and get a points if they win. so It shows on leader board as ranking. It's like "battle.net" of Warcraft 3 or Starcraft. Is it possible with just using game center?

[POINT]
- Can I play with random person?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can totally do that! game center allows you to match users of the same groups , you can sort your users into groups, (example: by their level) and game center allows you to match users based on these groups

[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW1) you can read up about matchmaking in game center, of course you will need to read up on most of gamecenter docs as this is not so much of a plug and play piece of code

similarly it leads to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW13) where they talk about player groups and how you sort your players into groups which you can add to your matchmaking request to sort matchrequest by groups so that players get someone of their own skill level

and yes it will be a random person

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GameKit supports [Leader boards](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13).

> In Game Center, a leaderboard is used to record scores earned by anyone who plays your game. Your game posts player scores to Game Center. When a player wants to see their scores, they bring up a leaderboard screen, either in the Game Center application or by viewing the leaderboard inside your game.

You can also use [matchmaking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW19) to create games with random persons.

> Your game can provide automatic matching to create a match. When you use automatic matching, players do not invite other players into the match. Instead, you send a request to Game Center and the player is connected into a match with any other players waiting to join a match (not just friends).